# Get precision of any decimal number

Tags: statistics

*(Sorry for the inconvenience related to the tags, please feel free to correct my post if it needs a better scope by adding some other tags).*

**CONTEXT**

I have several (decimal) numbers shaped like this :

- 1.081
- 289.089167
- 2.98
- ...

**PROBLEM**

I would like to get a decimal number, that I call "precision", which would give me the precision, which means the number of digits of this (decimal) number.

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

- 1.081 => **0.001**
- 289.089167 => **0.000001**
- 2.98 => **0.01**
- 67.00...n  => **0.0...(n-1)..1**

**ATEMPTS**

I work in IT, and most precisely on an audio apps. So I have a audio file in input, and it gives me the audio duration.

What I try to achieve is to set a range, which you can find in any other website shaped like following :

```
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="???" />
```

And initated to 0. The user can drag the cursor to change the currentTime of the audio, and to be the most precise possible, I have to get the precision, in order to set the "max='???'" like following :

```
max="getPrecision(audio.duration)"
```

I simplifyed the code, in reality the max property will be changed via JavaScript but it is not the aim of my question.

**QUESTION**

Does a mathematical formula exists to get this expected output ?

Comment: How are the numbers being stored? Strings? Base 10? Base 2? IEEE 754 floating point? You may have something 0.499999999999 (finite) but really those 99999...'s are useless. The precision is an intrisic part of how the measurement is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your input number is "$\color\red{n}.\color\green{m}$", the formula is "$\color\red{n}.\color\green{m}$"/"$\color\red{n}\color\green{m}$".

So in any scripting language, simply divide the rational number represented in the original string, by the integer number represented in the original string without the decimal point.

Comment: Putting your answer as correct instead of @Ant's answer because it also gives me "1" if the number has 0 digits after the dot (which was something I thought not possible !).

Comment: @Zeratops Of course that's your decision, but note that if $n=0$, then $10^{-n} = 10^0 = 1$. So my answer works too. Also it's a fair bet that my method is faster since constructing the integer $nm$ is not blazingly fast, and they one operates a long division. Calculating the length of the numbers instead is probably faster. Finally you should upvote all the answers you find useful, so (hopefully) both mine and barack manos's (as I did, for instance)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If there are $n$ digits after the dot, you want $10^{-n}$

Comment: I think that OP can't up-vote due to insufficient "rating" (or whatever you call it), so I'm making it equal :)